# Is it possible to choose first 4 elements using css?

Tags: javascript, css

It doesn't duplicate! I have such a structure:

```
    <ul>
        <li class="item">
         <div>
            <span>Option</span>
         </div>
       </li>
       <li class="item">
        <div>
          <span>Option<</span>
         </div>
       </li>
       <li class="item">
        <div>
         <span>Option<</span>
        </div>
       </li>
       <li class="item">
        <div>
         <span>Option<</span>
        </div>
       </li>
       <li class="item">
        <div>
         <span>Option<</span>
        </div>
       </li>
       <li class="item">
        <div>
         <span>Option<</span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
       <div>
        <span>Option<</span>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
       <div>
        <span>Option<</span>
       </div>
      </li>
<li class="item">
        <div>
         <span>Option<</span>
        </div>
       </li>
       <li class="item">
        <div>
         <span>Option<</span>
        </div>
       </li>
       <li class="item">
        <div>
         <span>Option<</span>
        </div>
       </li>        

   </ul>
```

scss is following:

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    max-height: stretch;
    li {
            font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    }
  }
```

I need to make first 4 list items with background color and after that make next without background and again repeat the same with next 4 elements, number of list element can be dynamic, on some screens I will do only first 2 elements with background. How can I choose 4 elements in odd rows using css?

Comment: I am not sure if this is a typo on the question or if your actual code has the same issue but you have a double chevron when closing your `span` elements (i.e. `<</span>`) you should remove one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to really select a range and repeat so make multiple rules

```css
ul li:nth-child(8n),
ul li:nth-child(8n-1),
ul li:nth-child(8n-2),
ul li:nth-child(8n-3) {
  background-color: lime;
  color: blue
}

ul li {
  color: green
}

ul li:nth-child(8n-7),
ul li:nth-child(8n-6),
ul li:nth-child(8n-5),
ul li:nth-child(8n-4) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The problem is that the number of elements can be dynamic

Comment: @rick1 what does that mean?

Comment: I can have 20 li elements, 30, 40 or 67. The number isn't fixed

Comment: So how does that make a difference? You said 4 than 4.... which is what this code does.

Comment: how to select odd elements but not even? Right now second row selected first but I need from first

Comment: So you change the nth-child selector.....

Comment: how?  li:nth-child(8n-1),
    li:nth-child(8n-2),
    li:nth-child(8n-3),
    li:nth-child(8n-4) {
      background-color: lime;
    } I did this but it didn't help

Comment: so subtract more or use a common class on the li and alter it in the nth-child section....

Comment: @LGSon I understand but I need solution right now, I do not have a lot of time to check articles

Comment: @epascarello thank you, it is working. I only need somehow to change hit to two elemnts in the row now for smaller screens

Comment: CSS Media queries....

Comment: @rick1 If you don't have time to learn, contact a web design company and they will produce it for you...as that is not what SO is for, to produce code on demand.

Comment: @epascarello queries yes, but selection of rows it is the problem...

Comment: @LGSon you could write some answer instead of writing about some company it would be much helpful

Comment: LOL @rick1 we are helping you for free.... just remember that. https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: @epascarello I know and I'm not working on commercial project. I know what queries mean. I just get tired when everytime I hear that some topic is duplicate because every situation is different

Answer (score -2):

The simplest solution would be to add different classes to add different styles. Example:

```
.blackLi {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.grayLi {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
```

Then add them to your li tags accordingly. For dynamic elements you can also add them programatically with the .classlist.add() method

Comment: No because on desktop one row will consist of 4 li elements and on mobile with 2

Comment: And how does that prevent you from using classes?